# How do print asterisk at random calendar output

Tags: java

I already got the program to print the calendar output. Now question is how do you print an asterisk at 7 random location (beside the day) in the calendar? I already managed to get the calendar print out. Any help is appreciated. Below is a code snippet.

[image: Calendar]

```
   for (int day = 1; day <= month.length; day++)
    {
      // print day
      System.out.printf("%1$4s", day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
int randomLocation = 7;    
for (int day = 1; day <= 30; day++)
            {
                // print day
                if(day == randomLocation) {
                    System.out.printf("%1$4s*", day);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.printf("%1$4s", day);
                }
            }
```

It will print like:
`5   6   7*   8` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a counter and a random number generator and for each day you generate a new random number, if bigger than 0.5 you add an asterisk and increment the counter. Keep doing this until you have generated all 7 of them. With this approach you would also need to introduce a mechanism to ensure that if you still need to generate `n` numbers and you still have `n` numbers to go, then the remaining `n` numbers will be generated with an asterisk near them.

Another solution would be to create a list of all the possible days, shuffle it through `Collections.shuffle` and take the first 7 elements from it and place it in a new list, say `randomDays`. Then, when you are iterating and printing, you check to see if the current day is within `randomDays`. If it is, then you print the asterisk next to it.